# Create a permutation with longest increasing subsequence length 3

Tags: mathematics

Create a permutation of the integers 1 to 30 with [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) length 3. An important part of the definition is that a
subsequence is not necessarily contiguous or unique.

Comment: Are the downvotes because the question is simple to solve?

Comment: Didn't downvote but I suppose it might have been because this seems more like a pure maths problem not really a puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to be a simple solution:

> 30, 29, 28, ..., 6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3
>  It has only one increasing subsequence, which happens to be consecutive and contiguous, and of length 3.
>
>  Slightly more generally, you can take the sequence 30, 29, 28, ..., 6, 5, 4, 3 and insert the 2 anywhere to the left of the final 3, and then the 1 anywhere to the left of the 2.
>
>  Even more generally, you can take the complete reversed sequence 30, 29, 28, ..., 4, 3, 2, 1 and pick any two numbers other than 30. Move the first chosen number one or more places to the left, and then move the second number to the left at least past the first number.

Comment: A fast and correct solution. Can you find another one?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, which you might perhaps regard as not so simple:

10, 20, 30, 9, 19, 29, ..., 1, 11, 21.

An increasing sequence $a, b, c$ needs $a<11$, $10<b<21$ and $c>20$.

Comment: I like it a lot.